# Season in Forcasting in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, visualization, prediction, accumulate, seasoned-schemer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYdtd.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSNIa.png)

my data is a monthly accumulated revenue table. start at the beginning day of the month and end at the ending day of the month.
in my tableau forcasting, it cannot detect the season = 1 month as Excel can do. as you can see in my picture that tableau set season = 7 days.
Pls help me to change the season setup in Tableau.
so many thanks.

Comment: can you share your workbook so we can look at the data within it? it's harder to understand the issue otherwise

Comment: I edited my post with an image of my data in excel with forcasting in excel when excel automatically recognized the season of 30 days cycle.